# Access Ribbon callback function cannot be inside report

Tags: ms-access, ribbon

Below is my ribbon code for report

```
<button id="EmailPDF" label = "Email Customer" 
    size="large"
    imageMso="FileEmailAsPdfEmailAttachment"
    onAction="=Rpt_Email()"
    supertip= "Email to customer."/>
```

And this is my callback function

```
Public Function Rpt_Email() As Boolean
    MsgBox "OK"
End Function
```

Call back function works, if it is in module.  But, it does not work, if I move it to Report.  I need it to be on the report.  Because, I need to access each report information and setup email accordingly.

Comment: Could have code opening report or code behind report set some global variables or TempVars then the Rpt_Email function references those variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Callbacks need to be in public modules, and can't be in class modules, form modules or report modules.

Instead, use `Screen.ActiveReport` to determine which report is active from that global module. Or, create separate functions and ribbons per report, and show them as the report ribbon (this has the additional advantage of not showing the ribbon if none of the reports are open).

Comment: On my system, call back can be in form modules.  I have 100+ call back on form module.  This is the first call back I want to save it on Report module.

Comment: Your suggestion Screen.ActiveReport is a good idea and I will try.